# Как правильно сконкатенировать строки из одно DataFrame в другой без прохода?

Tags: python, pandas, дата, dataframe

Есть два df, второй из которых очень большой и содержит разделенные по столбцам даты.

```
df1
                 day    month    year
    0             21        4    2020
    1             20        4    2020
    2             19        4    2020
    3             18        4    2020
    ...
    2189345        1        3    1932
```

Требуется в первом df эти столбцы объединить в одну дату с разделителем "точка"; то есть, например, получить 21.04.2020. Как это сделать **без прохода** по df1?

Желаемый результат:

```
df2
                       date
    0            21.04.2020
    1            20.04.2020
    2            19.04.2020
    3            18.04.2020
    ...
    2189345      01.03.1932
```

Пытался так, как приведено ниже. Результата, разумеется, не получил, и понимаю, почему:

```
df2.loc[:, 'Период'] = df1.loc[:, 'day'] + df1.loc[:, 'month'] + df1.loc[:, 'year']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться просто конкатенацией

```
df1[ 'day'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + '.' \
+  df1['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + '.' \
+ df1['year'].astype(str
```